# code crashes when int arr = 1 && arr; but not int arr = 0 && arr;

Tags: c

I wanted to know why the following code crashes.

```
int main( ) 
{  
    int arr = 1 && arr;
    return 0; 
}
```

BUT not with the below code

```
int main( ) 
{  
    int arr = 0 && arr;
    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Crashes? What do you mean by "crashes"? What platform are you using, if it "crashes" on manipulation with an uninitialized `int`?

Comment: Andrey, it seems odd to me too (I would expect the program to continue despite the indeterminate value of `arr`), but the standard (http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says simply reading the value invokes undefined behavior: C99 J. 2 (Undefined Behavior): "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate."

Comment: I've tried both of these functions with VS2005 - although the first function gives a compile warning, for me neither of them crash at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`0 && arr`
The above expression is *false* because of `0`, so `arr` is not checked unlike `1 && arr` where `arr` has to be checked to evaluate the value for expression.

---

You should try:

```
int main(){
  int a = 0 && printf("a"); //printf returns number of characters printed, 1
  int b = 1 && printf("b");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of short circuit evaluation of boolean expressions. In the first example the left side of the && operator evaluates to true so the right is evaluated. In the second case the left is false so the right is never evaluated.